# What does 'scape mean in this quote by Shakespeare?

Tags: meaning, archaic-language, elision, early-modern-english

I found this line in Hamlet by William Shakespeare.

> And 'scape detecting, I will pay the theft.

What does "'scape" mean? Google says this.

> 1. A long, leafless flower stalk coming directly from a root.
> 2. The basal segment of an insect's antenna, esp. when it is enlarged and lengthened (as in a weevil).

Should I read this as "And flower stalk detecting, I will pay the theft."?

Comment: Ah, but that quote doesn't contain the word *scape*. What it contains is *'scape*, which is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The apostrophe at the beginning is your clue that it is missing a letter or two.  The word is

> [***escape***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/escape) : (transitive) To avoid (any unpleasant person or thing); to elude, get away from.