# what is 'set up transpo'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the movie *Zodiac* (2007), after Dave Toschi gets to the crime scene in which a taxi driver was killed in his cab, he was informed by a local cop that

> Neighborhood's pretty high-end for this, so I already set up transpo for the cab.

What does 'set up transpo' mean and how is it realted to the neighborhood being high-end?

Comment: Arranged for a tow-truck to haul it away, I would think.  transport. They would need to ensure chain-of-custody of evidence. The oddity is "so".

Comment: Was that from the movie's script, or what you heard? Movie dialog can be very local or slack. As a native English speaker, I often have to rewind both UK and US movies to catch the dialog.

Comment: By the way, the verb "was informed" lacks a grammatical subject in your question. Who was informed?

Comment: Guess: the taxi should be removed from the scene of crime as soon as possible, because it is a posh neighbourhood.

Comment: @Weather Vane That was my first thought, so I checked it online in the script.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Right. He was informed... I'll edit it right away.

Comment: @Weather Vane: The inference to be drawn is that if it were not a posh neighborhood, they would be less concerned about promptly ensuring chain-of-custody. See page 111ff. here: https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/forensics/Crime-Scene-Investigation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't listen to them!

*...Shouldn't us native-English-speakers be directing the "learners" to better examples of the English language, rather than misdirecting them by discussing possible interpretation of fiction/literature?  (Much like [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4084/what-does-scape-mean-in-this-quote-by-shakespeare) on this site asking for interpretation of 1500's [Shakespeare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare)?!)*

***If the purpose of this site is to learn to communicate clearly in English, then some important things should be noted:***

You're asking about the definition of a piece of "cop slang" spoken by an *amateur* detective in a *fictional* [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443706/) which is based in the 1960's (~60 years ago), and even then, "transpo" was [not a word that would be spoken](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=transpo%2C%20transportation&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctranspo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctransportation%3B%2Cc0B%2Cc0) by most people, *ever*<sup>*</sup>.  **This is not a good example of how to communicate with *real people* in 2018.**

<sup>* In Ontario, Canada, "[TRANSPO](http://www.octranspo.com/?from=splash)" is more commonly used since it is the name of the public pransportation (transit) system.  Wikipedia's only other [entries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpo) are also related to transit systems.</sup>

---

> ### **slang** *noun* ​ /slæŋ/
>
> ***Very informal* language that is usually *spoken* rather than written,**
>   **used especially by *particular groups* of people.**  <sub>([Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slang))</sub>

---

If you would like to learn by examples of others speaking current ("normal") present-day English, fiction is not a good resource.  Even [the movies` reviews](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443706/reviews) would be a much better

**A list of *more* police slang that you shouldn't use:**

- [List of police-related slang terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_police-related_slang_terms)

> Many slang terms, **often considered derogatory or offensive**, exist
>   for police officers. These terms are rarely used by the police
>   themselves and instead are used by immigrants, criminals, prisoners,
>   or by the general public. <sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_police-related_slang_terms))</sub>

There's even an iPhone app to teach us all about "cop slang":

- http://www.copslang.com/

On that site, note that the screen-shots of the app include the phrases:

- Turd Cutter
- Lot Lizard
- Ass Hat

...not recommended for usage in everyday speaking!

> Police services also have their own internal slang and jargon; some of
>   it is relatively widespread geographically and some very localized.

- Current (real-life) [Law Enforcement terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Law_enforcement_terminology)
- [40 American Slang Words and Phrases You Need to Know](https://www.smartling.com/blog/40-american-slang-words-and-phrases-you-need-to-know/)

If you would like to use movies to help you learn English, I would highly recommend that you steer away from fiction for now, and instead check out some of the 1000's of documentaries available, such as:

- [The best documentaries on Netflix](https://www.google.ca/search?q=best%20documentaries%20on%20netflix&num=100)
- [The best documentaries on YouTube](https://www.google.ca/search?q=best%20documentaries%20on%20youtube&num=100)

---

Answer (score 1):

"Transpo" is not an English word, but from context I would interpret it as being short for "Transport" or "Transportation". The rest of the phrase, "set up", is well-understood to me but finding the relevant precise definition was more challenging than expected. I finally found for the word "set" a list of verb phrases under which definition 115.i finally got pretty close:

> to propound; plan; advance

Specifically, "plan" is close. I would understand the phrase as meaning that the speaker plans to have the cab moved, with the implication that the plan is already started such as by calling a tow truck.

The relation to being in a high-end neighborhood isn't explicitly stated, but my guess would be that murder or the specific circumstances of the murder are unusual for the neighborhood so he(?) wants to remove the disturbance as soon as possible.